# Use activities for New Element Wizard

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I'm trying to use `org.eclipse.activities` in order to enable/disable a new element wizard(for example I want to hide the "new java Class wizard"). When I add the wizard ID to the activity, I can still select the the new element wizard from "Select a Wizard" and promts a dialog asking me if I want to enable this activity. How can I hide this wizard from the "Select a wizard" tree or disable the Confirm Enablement dialog?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem by myself. The main problem was that when the wizard is as "primaryWizard" set, It doesn't get removed from the Tree. I was looking the whole time the primary Wizards, not the one in the category. So if you need to hide an wizard, all you need to do is to add the following extension:

```xml
      <extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.activities">
          <activity
              id="de.de.de.enableFeatureOne"
              name="Enable Feature">
          </activity>
          <activityPatternBinding
               activityId="de.de.de.enableFeatureOne"
               pattern="pluginID/elementID">
          </activityPatternBinding>
      </extension>
```